# What are the :class Attributes in Laravel Spark/Vue.js

Tags: php, css, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

In Laravel spark, a `<div/>` enclosing a rendered form element might look like this

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': form.errors.has('name')}">

</div>
```

That is -- is has a `:class` attribute.  What is this?  I get the intent/behavior -- if the `form.errors.hash('name')` call returns true (with `form` being a `SparkForm` set on the enclosing component) then the div will have an `has-error` class.  However, what makes `:class` work?  My first assumption was it's a Vue.js thing, but if I read [the Vue docs on class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), it (seems like?) Vue.js expects an attribute named `v-bind:class`

```
<div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{'has-error': form.errors.has('name')}">

</div>
```

So what makes `:class` work?  Is this a Vue.js provided short cut? (if so, is it documented somewhere?).

Is this some patented Laravel syntactic sugar to make writing templates a bit less verbose?  If so, where's this implemented?

Is it some third thing?

Comment: Vuejs shorthands :  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands

Comment: Thanks @mohammad -- if you want to write that up as a formal answer I'm happy to up vote and mark it as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what makes :class work? Is this a Vue.js provided short cut? (if
> so, is it documented somewhere?).

Yes , Its a Vuejs Shorthand

document: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands

> The `v-` prefix serves as a visual cue for identifying Vue-specific
> attributes in your templates. This is useful when you are using Vue.js
> to apply dynamic behavior to some existing markup, but can feel
> verbose for some frequently used directives. At the same time, the
> need for the `v-` prefix becomes less important when you are building an
> SPA where Vue.js manages every template. Therefore, Vue.js provides
> special shorthands for two of the most often used directives, `v-bind`
> and `v-on`:

there is no diffrence between

```
:class="{'has-error': form.errors.has('name')}
```

and

```
v-bind:class="{'has-error': form.errors.has('name')}
```